# Is there a way to resolve dependency from one repository?

Tags: maven

I have a test project and I would like to make sure that dependency will be exclusively resolved from the local repository.

Can this be done?

Does maven have functionality similar to Gradle [exclusiveContent](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html#declaring_content_exclusively_found_in_one_repository)?

Comment: The easiest and best way to make sure that the dependency is drawn from a given repository is to give it a unique version (like 1.2.3-TEST-SNAPSHOT) and use that version.

Comment: The main problem here is that - this version will be dynamic - from a library project perspective I want to push the current version to the local maven repo, from a test project perspective I want to pull this lib and check if everything is working fine. I would like to avoid updating the version on the test project BTW I need maven central because the test project relies on some of the dependencies available there

Comment: So why could the same version appear in a remote repository and your local repository?